# Resize text in mathmode in a bend arrow

Tags: tikz-pgf, math-mode, tikz-arrows, decorations

I want to change the size of a math text in a curved arrow, but whenever I manage to change the size, the text is no longer curved. My code is

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                calc,
                positioning,
                decorations.text,
                intersections}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [->,postaction={decorate,
                        decoration={
                                    raise=0.5ex,
                                    text along path,
                                    text align={center},
                                    text={$a+b+c$},
        reverse path}}] (1,0) to [bend right=45] (-1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I've tried several suggestions posted here, but they don't work. I tried some also using `XeLaTex` and I couldn't either.

What I would like is to be able to change the font size of a mathematical formula, in this case using `\tiny` or `\scripsize` for example. Would anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\tiny` is not a math size. You can use `\scriptstyle` or `\scriptscriptstyle`

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, decorations.text}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [<-,postaction={decorate,
decoration={
  raise=0.5ex,
  text along path,
  text align={center},
  text={|\scriptstyle|$a+b+c$},
}}] (-1,0) to[bend left=45] (1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Bend arrow with math]